# Can Unity read an input from bluetooth keyboard on iOS?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, unity-game-engine, ios-bluetooth

Unity doesn't seem to get any data from bluetooth keyboard on iOS. Keyboard is paired and works on all other apps, but on Unity Input.GetKeyDown() never returns true. I tried it with two different keyboards and none of them worked. I also tested the same project on Android and there everything works as expected. Is there a way to make bluetooth keyboard work on iOS?

Comment: it actually tried the same yesterday on tvOS without any luck.

Comment: This is weird, it would be nice to clarify somethings if you played a unity game with the same keyboard. Would it detect?

Comment: @GabrielCapeletti I didn't try it with other Unity games as I don't know any that would use keyboard as input method. But the same keyboards work perfectly well on all other apps I tried them with (Evernote, Browsers etc.). So I suppose it's Unity specific thing. I Googled a lot about the issue and the only things I was able to find were the similar questions as mine with zero answers.

Answer (score 0):

modify the native code in Xcode after you build the unity project on IOS platform.And you may use UIKeyCommand class in the "UIkit" framework in some UIViewController.Hope it may help you !

Comment: There are several limitations using the `UIKeyCommand` method. You have to setup each key press you want to detect individually. Also, there is no way to get key-up notifications.